# Wildfly Swarm Rest Controller

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly-swarm

I'm using jar based Wildfly Swarm with main method. As I understand when you are using war based app you should create some class which extends `Application` class. But it's not works for jar based app. Is it possible to configure somehow? In case if only one way is using `JAXRSArchive` is possible to add all class to it in other way then manually call `addResource` to each class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recommend having `war` packaging when you want a WAR deployment.

Trying to have a WAR deployment constructed from a project with `jar` packaging in Maven makes it more difficult because the deployment isn't created for you.

May I ask what you require the main() method for, as we're trying to move away from that?